# Problems with pwrite() to a file in C/C++

Tags: c++, linux

I've a bad problem. I'm trying to write to a file via filedescriptor and memalign. I can write to it but only something like an wrong encoded char is written to a file.

Here's my code:

```
fdOutputFile = open(outputFile, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_DIRECT, 0644)

void writeThis(char* text) {
    while (*text != '\0') {
        // if my internal buffer is full -> write to disk
        if (buffPositionOutput == outputbuf.st_blksize) {
            posix_memalign((void **)&bufferO, outputbuf.st_blksize, outputbuf.st_blksize);

            cout << "wrote " << pwrite(fdOutputFile, bufferO, outputbuf.st_blksize, outputOffset*outputbuf.st_blksize) << " Bytes to disk." << endl;
            buffPositionOutput = 0;
            ++outputOffset;
        }

        // buffer the incoming text...
        bufferO[buffPositionOutput] = *text;
        ++text;
        ++buffPositionOutput;
    }
}
```

I think it's the alignment - can someone help me?
It writes to the file but not the correct text, just a bunch of '[]'-chars.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your program, here is what happens:

1. You fill the memory initially pointed to by `buffer0+buffPositionOutput` (Which is where, precisely?  I don't know based on the code you give.) up to `buffer0+outputbuf.st_blksize` with data.
2. You pass the address of the `buffer0` pointer to `posix_memalign`, which ignores its current value and overwrites it with a pointer to `outputbuf.st_blksize` bytes of newly-allocated memory.
3. You write data from the newly-allocated block to disk; this might be anything, since you just allocated memory and haven't written anything there yet.

This won't work, obviously.  You probably want to initialize your buffer via `posix_memalign` at the top of your function, and then just overwrite the block's worth of data in it as you use your aligned buffer to repeatedly write data into the file.  (Reset `buffpositionoutput` to zero after each time you write data, but don't re-allocate.)  Make sure you `free` your buffer when you are done.

Also, why are you using `pwrite` instead of `write`?

Here's how I would implement `writeThis` (keeping your variable names so you can match it up with your version):

```
void writeThis(char *text) {
    char *buffer0;
    size_t buffPositionOutput = 0;
    posix_memalign(&buffer0, outputbuf.st_blksize, outputbuf.st_blksize);
    while (*text != 0) {
        ++text; ++buffPositionOutput;
        if (buffPositionOutput == outputbuf.st_blksize) {
            write(fdOutputFile, buffer0, outputbuf.st_blksize);
            buffPositionOuput = 0;
        }
    }
    if (buffPositionOutput != 0) {
        // what do you want to do with a partial block of data?  Not sure.
    }
}
```

(For speed, you might consider using `memcpy` calls instead of a loop.  You would need to know the length of the data to write ahead of time though.  Worry about that after you have a working solution that does not leak memory.)

Comment: the memalign is required because of the use of `O_DIRECT` - that requires block-sized chunks of aligned data on linux (IIRC). Not sure why `pwrite` though.

Comment: Ah, right.  Revising to drop the question for easier reading going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-allocating `buffer0` every time you try to output it, and not freeing it. That's really not efficient (and leaks memory). I'd suggest you refactor your code a bit, because it's quite hard to follow whether your bounds checking on that buffer is correct or not.

Allocate `buffer0` only once somewhere (form that snippet, storing it in `outputbuf` sounds like a good idea). Also store buffPositionOutput in that struct (or in another struct, but close to that buffer).

```
// in setup code
int rc = posix_memalign(&(outputbuf.data), outputbuf.st_blksize,
                                           outputbuf.st_blksize);
// check rc!
outputbuf.writePosition = 0;
```

```
// in cleanup code
free(outputbuf.data);
```

Then you can rewrite your function like this:

```
void writeThis(char *text) {
   while (*text != 0) {
     outputbuf.data[outputbuf.writePosition] = *text;
     outputbuf.writePosition++;
     text++;
     if (outputbuf.writePosition == outputbuf.block_size) {
        int rc = pwrite(...);
        // check rc!
        std::cout << ...;
        outputbuf.writePosition = 0;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think C/C++ has encodings. ASCII only.
Unless you use wchar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character